# Expected value of $X^{\top}(XAX^{\top})^{-1}X$ for large random $X$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a random matrix where the entries are i.i.d. standard normal, and let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a deterministic diagonal matrix with positive entries on the diagonal. How to calculate the expectation
$$
M=\mathbb{E}\left[X^{\top}\left(XAX^{\top}\right)^{-1}X\right]
$$
in the limit $m,n\rightarrow\infty$ and $m/n\rightarrow c$ where $c<1$ ?

Is it possible to use the Marchenko–Pastur law for this case ?

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly the matrix inside the expectation is of diverging size $n\times n$, so how can you even define that limit?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The limit is for every entry of the matrix, and if it is possible to calculate the expectation for any finite $m<n$ (not in the limit) it will be better.
For example, consider the case where $A=aI$. In this case, using SVD $X=U\Sigma V^{\top}$ we get that the expectation is a scalar matrix $a^{-1}\frac{m}{n}I$.

Comment: I still don't get it. What size are those two identity matrices supposed to be (in the limit, for the second one)? Shouldn't $A$ be replaced by a family of matrices $A_n$, in general? Defined how?

Comment: Size $n\times n$. In general when $n\rightarrow\infty$, $A$ is a sequence of diagonal matrices $A_n$. The expectation should depend somehow on the values on the diagonal. Anyway, if it is possible to calculate the expectation for finite $n$ it will be great.

Comment: two extreme cases: for $m=n$ the average matrix is $M=A^{-1}$, for $m=1$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$ it is $M=I/({\rm tr}\,A)$.